# using oni files in openni_camera node

Tags: openni, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo,

I've tried to get the .oni files as input instead of the camera by changing the initialization to the way the NiViewer example works with the xml file (status = context_.InitFromXmlFile(SAMPLE_XML_PATH, &errors);) . It works when selecting input sources from the camera that way, but when giving an .oni file with rgb and depth streams in I get this error:

```
[31m[ERROR] [1298297598.491463836]: [OpenNIDriver::spin] Error in switching on depth stream registration: This operation is invalid![0m
[31m[ERROR] [1298297599.031286629]: [OpenNIDriver::spin] Error in switching on depth stream registration: This operation is invalid![0m
[31m[ERROR] [1298297599.031449831]: [OpenNIDriver::spin] Error in switching on depth stream registration: This operation is invalid![0m
```

Same settings work fine with NiViewer but I seem to be missing something to get it to work in the openni_camera node but I don't see it.
Any idea's what I'm missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9150/using-oni-files-in-openni_camera-node/) by [Wilco](https://answers.ros.org/users/158/wilco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The openni_cameara node is designed to read from the device and output ROS messages.  As far as I know it doesn't have support for ONI recording or playback.  If you want, you can make a feature request of it at https://kforge.ros.org/openni/Trac/newticket?component=openni_kinect&keywords=openni_camera&type=enhancement

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1